# How to access HeaderTemplate value in code behind

Tags: asp.net

In my gridview there is one HeaderTemplate like below mentioned code

```
 <HeaderTemplate>
     Source
 </HeaderTemplate>
```

And I need to get "Source" in code behind. How can I resolve this? Please help me on this.

Comment: As above mentioned Gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
string headerText = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text;
```